# Error: Could not find the include file "partials/head"

Tags: node.js, ejs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gog14.png)I am trying to run an ejs file and gets error Error: Could not find the include file "partials/head".

i have checked most of the articles from stackoverflow and github however not able to resolve it ...

> Error: Could not find the include file "partials/head"
>       at getIncludePath (C:\Users\Junia\Desktop\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:162:13) enter
>   code here    at includeSource
>   (C:\Users\Junia\Desktop\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:306:17)
>       at C:\Users\Junia\Desktop\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:672:26
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Template.generateSource (C:\Users\Junia\Desktop\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:648:15)
>       at Template.compile (C:\Users\Junia\Desktop\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:552:12)
>       at Object.compile (C:\Users\Junia\Desktop\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:388:16)
>       at handleCache (C:\Users\Junia\Desktop\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:212:18)
>       at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\Junia\Desktop\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:251:16)
>       at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\Junia\Desktop\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:480:10)

```
var express=require('express');

var app=express();

var router=express.Router();

var mysql=require('mysql');

var cookieParser=require('cookie-parser');

var session=require('express-session');

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
    //cookie : { maxAge : 60000 }
}));

var path=require('path');

var bodyParser=require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static('/'));

//Serves all the request which includes /images in the url from Images folder

app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/images'));

app.use('/bs4', express.static(__dirname + '/bs4'));

app.use(cookieParser());

const ejsLint = require('ejs-lint');

var con=mysql.createConnection(

{

host:'localhost',

user:'root',

password:'',

database:'shintoj'

});

var path = require('path');

app.use('/',router);

app.use('/',express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/pages'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');// use res.render to load up an ejs view file

// index page 

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    //res.send('Welcome');

    res.render('index');

});

app.listen(8080);

console.log('8080 is the magic port');

console.log(app.get('views'));
```

index.ejs file

```
<head>

<%- include partials/head %>

</head>

<body class="container">

<header>

<% include partials/header.ejs %>

</header>

    <div class="jumbotron">

        <h2>Welcome to our services .</h2>

        <p>Hello</p>

    </div>

<footer>

<% include partials/footer.ejs %>

</footer>
```

expected actual result is ..
when i run node server.js , it should display the index.ejs file

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html language="en">

<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
<% include partials/head %>
</head>

<body class="container">

<header>
<% include partials/header.ejs %>

</header>

 <div class="jumbotron">
  <h2>Welcome to our services .</h2>
  <p>Hello</p>
 </div>

<footer>
<% inlcude partials/footer.ejs %>
</footer> 

</body>

</html>

Answer (score 2):

That's because your ejs file is in another directory which is views
which mean that your partials directory is outside if your views directory..

Try this:

```
<%- include('../partials/head.ejs') %>
```

Answer (score 2):

##### In 2021, October

I'm also having the same issue with importing files on `ejs`. But I used to figure it out the following way to include my other `ejs` partials from the parent directory.

#### Pros

1. Don't need to set up `view engine and directory path` on server file.
2. Independent directory names and locations we can achieve.

##### Working file: `src/views/en/confirmation.ejs`

##### Parent file: `src/views/common/footer.ejs` (Needs to included on each ejs file)

##### In src/views/en/confirmation.ejs`

```js
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html data-editor-version="2" class="sg-campaigns" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <body>
         <h1>this is body</h1>
     </body>
     
     <% var dir = process.cwd() %>
     <%- include(dir + "/src/views/common/footer.ejs") %>
  
</html>
```

Comment: FYI for serverless users: this worked for me on serverless.yml project without using copy file plugin or anything else

Answer (score 1):

Remove include tag header and footer from ejs tag in your index.ejs file.
Or jsut include header and footer file properly. Like this

```
<%- include views-directory/filename  %>
```

Comment: if i remove include it works fine ..but when i use include with the proper directory call it does not work.          .Error: Could not find the include file "views/partials/head"
    at getIncludePath (C:\Users\Junia\Desktop\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:162:13)
    at includeSource

Comment: Where is your index.ejs file. Can you show me directory of view?

Comment: Root Folder named ->node- views-pages-index.ejs and the server.js in the node folder

Comment: Issue is resolved with this <%- include ../partials/head  %> Thank you

Comment: this is out the outdated answer and it's completely deprecated now. **DON'T USE IT** or you'll end up with an error.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue while implementing and after investing around 2-3 hr I figured out I was writing

```
<%- include ('partials/header') %>
```

instead of

```
<%- include('partials/header') %>
```

Well, the only difference was the space between include and opening bracket.

Answer (score -1):

I also came across the same issue when I change the location of header and footer from **views** to its subfolder **partials**.
And, in order to reach new header and footer location, I updated the path inside the string as below and it worked for me-

```
<%- include('./partials/header'); -%>

<!-- file path for footer.ejs -->

<%- include('./partials/footer'); -%>
```

Answer (score -2):

This can happen, given the way you are calling the page you need, currently the correct way to get one page within another is

```
<%- include('partials/navigation.html')%>
```

Comment: ejs file only can include other `ejs` file not a `html` files.