# how i can fix that?Could not find the include file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

`Error: C:\Users\Qasem\Desktop\New folder\views\index.ejs:1`

```
 1. <%- include('parts/hearder')%>
 2. <%- include('parts/navbar')%>
 3. <%- include('parts/footer')%>
```

Could not find the include file "parts/hearder"
    at getIncludePath (C:\Users\Qasem\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:166:13)
    at includeFile (C:\Users\Qasem\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:292:19)
    at include (C:\Users\Qasem\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:660:16)
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\Qasem\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:632:12), :10:17)
    at index (C:\Users\Qasem\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\Qasem\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:255:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\Qasem\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:461:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\Qasem\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\Qasem\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\Qasem\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)

Comment: Try `<%- include('./parts/navbar')%>`

Comment: Error: C:\Users\Qasem\Desktop\New folder\views\index.ejs:1
 >> 1| <%- include('./parts/hearder')%>

    2| 

    3| <%- include('./parts/navbar')%>

Comment: Do you have a folder parts with navbar file in it in views folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Could not find the include file "partials/head"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54731348/error-could-not-find-the-include-file-partials-head)

Comment: Show us your folder Structure