# Node.js - EJS - including a partial : error : Could not find the include file "partials/navbar.ejs" in nodejs app

Tags: node.js, express, web-applications, ejs, partial

Could not find the include file "partials/navbar.ejs"  in nodejs app

about Node.js - EJS - including a partial

Could not find the include file "partials/navbar.ejs"  in nodejs app

about Node.js - EJS - including a partial

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question needs more information in order to be answered. In any case, a similar issue was reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54731348/error-could-not-find-the-include-file-partials-head). I hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It look like your Node.js application is having trouble to locating the partial file "partials/navbar.ejs".

Please check the below steps to ensure everything is as expected.

- Double-check the file path.
- Verify file extension and its should be .ejs file format.
- Check file permissions.
- Restart the server if you did any changes in the application file.
- Try to put some logs to debug more in details.

Still encountering issues, providing more details about your directory structure and the code where you're including the partial would be helpful for further assistance.