# EJS including partials in nested directories relative to set views path

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Currently I'm using Express with EJS as the templating engine. My issue is the path being relative to the current directory within nested views instead of the set base view directory without resorting to hacks.

My views directory is structured as the following

```
+--/views
  |
  +--partials/
  | |
  | +--header.ejs
  | +--footer.ejs
  |
  +--pages/
  | |
  | +--blog/
  | | |
  | | +--new.ejs
  | | +--show.ejs
  | |
  | +--landing.ejs
  | +--(More files)
  |
  +--index.html
```

I am setting a views directory in express

`app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));`

In pages/landing.ejs I use

`<% include ../partials/header %>`

In deeper nested views such as pages/blog/new.ejs

`<% include ../../partials/header %>`

and it works, my intention is to use with the base path is relative to the set view directory in both files as follows:

`<% include partials/header %>`

Does EJS Support this natively?

Comment: I would like to avoid the hack to workaround in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44534998/12080438)

Answer (score 1):

(Other solutions looked a little complicated, so I decided to send my solution too). I tested it on Heroku and it worked fine.

1. Create `app-locals.js` and write this inside it:

```js
module.exports = {
  layouts:  process.cwd() + '/views/layouts/',
  partials: process.cwd() + '/views/partials/',
}
```

2. In `app.js`:

```js
// const express = require('express')
// const appLocals = require('./app-locals.js')

// const app = express()
app.locals = appLocals
```

3. Use it like:

```js
<%- include(partials + 'header.ejs') %>
```

Or you can do it like this:

```js
// app-locals.js
module.exports = {
    // Remove the last /
  layouts:  process.cwd() + '/views/layouts',
  partials: process.cwd() + '/views/partials',
}

// app.js
// Add / after the path
<%- include(`${partials}/header.ejs`) %>
```

- If you are using this on Heroku, make sure that your files and folder names all are lowercase and that you are using the same case when including the files.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is not supported by EJS. However, I have described a hack in this answer [EJS include file relative to project root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487980/ejs-include-file-relative-to-project-root/44534998#44534998)

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: I have seen your answer before posting, thank you for the solution. I was hoping for one without resorting to hacks. I will look into alternative engines as I seem to hit EJS(s) limitations often.