# Partial ejs file not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, backend, partials

## Ejs partials could not be found | NODE JS

> Could not find the include file "partials/header"

For some reason my NODE JS program couldn't find the **.ejs** file i am trying to include in my file.

### File System

> My path of views looks like

```
views
    ├───page
    │       index.ejs
    │
    └───partials
            footer.ejs
            header.ejs
```

### Source Codes

> Index.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>News Node App</title>
    <%- include("partials/header"); %>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="d-flex">
          
            <%for (let i =0;i<articles.length;i++){ let currNews = articles[i]%>
                <li>
                <div class="news-cars">
                    <%=currNews.title%>
                </div>
                </li>
            <%}%>
          </ol>
      </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

> header.ejs
> I am planning to add navbar later

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

### ERROR LOG

The full log to the error is given below

```
Error: D:\node\blog-app\views\page\index.ejs:7
    5|     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    6|     <title>News Node App</title>

    7|     <%- include("partials/header"); %>

    8|   </head>

    9|   <body>

    10|       <div class="d-flex">


Could not find the include file "partials/header"<br>
    at getIncludePath (D:\node\blog-app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:183:13)<br>
    at includeFile (D:\node\blog-app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:309:19)<br>
    at include (D:\node\blog-app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:689:16)<br>
    at eval (D:\node\blog-app\views\page\index.ejs:10:17)<br>
    at index (D:\node\blog-app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:691:17)<br>
    at tryHandleCache (D:\node\blog-app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)<br>
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\node\blog-app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)<br>
    at View.render (D:\node\blog-app\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)<br>
    at tryRender (D:\node\blog-app\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)<br>
    at Function.render (D:\node\blog-app\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)<br>
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\node\blog-app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)<br>
    at D:\node\blog-app\controllers\news-controller.js:10:25<br>
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)<br>
```

Comment: note that the file path is resolved relative to the server code (not the `view` path set) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6609132/11984670), also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487980/ejs-include-file-relative-to-project-root)

Comment: Yes brother. That was the error indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `./partials/header`.
You should also set the views engine in your main.js file `app.set('view engine','ejs')`. After installing the `ejs` package.

Comment: this solved it, it's the dot the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should not need the semicolon after your `<%- -%>` tags.  Change your ejs tags to include `-` on both tags.  Also, check that your server file has `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`  Lastly, make sure your server file is on the same hierarchical level as the `views` folder.